# What does "cosy study" mean?

Tags: meaning

I found this sentence in Cambridge Collocation in Use:

> It’s got a spacious living room which has a wonderful view of the
>   park, and a **cosy study** where we can both work.

So please what is the meaning of *cosy study*? Which room is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A study is a special room in a residential house which is used for reading, writing or academic work. The adjective *cosy* means giving a feeling of comfort, warmth and relaxation. Those are the definitions I got straight from my dictionary. So, a cozy study is a room in your house where you can go to study or do other work-related activities and you feel all warm and comfortable working there.

Example:

> He spent the entire day working on his new project in his study.

Here's what a typical study looks like:

[[image]

Comment: So there is no need to say " cosy study room"?

Comment: No. *study* is just one word.

Comment: could you please say examples? so can I say I'm in the study.

Comment: Yes. You could say to you wife: **If you need me, honey, I will be in the study working.**

Comment: Note that while *cosy* means "warm and comfortable," it also has connotations of being small in size.  It's kind of a running joke that real estate listings will use the word "cosy" specifically as a way of avoiding saying "very small."  In the original example, this is probably meant to be the case, since the "cosy study" is directly contrasted with the "spacious living room."